# Different between 100 rows and 100 million rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Think I have two table and each table have one index .

now I join tables by indexed column

my question is that is there any different on time whether each table have 100 rows or 1 million rows ?

Comment: Surely there is. You could try and benchmark (if 100M rows are too much, try just with 10, 100, 1000, 10000, ... 1 million rows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let say you are searching for your a book in a library. Is there any different on time whether  the library has 100 books or has 100 million books? Even the library nicely organize the book by category and by alphabetical order. It makes different. Computer is nothing different from us human, just it can perform some task a lot faster than us.

Let say we have 100 books to search. Using binary search will takes log2(100) = 6.64 operations. 100,000,000 books takes log2(100,000,000) = 26.57 operations.

Comment: can you describe more about log 2 operations , what operations means ?

Comment: @Ata: Read about [time complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity), and probably learn a bit more math.

Answer (score 1):

it depends on several things

1. what is the ralation between them if it is one to one there is not much difference
2. what is you query if it is where=some_key it is ok (and relation is one to one)
3. Indexing, in large table you have to use columns with keys to prevent full  table scan in table with 100 rows it will not have much difference if the query not uses the index

in general diffenrence in speed will have if relations is different from one-one and/or you are using some query different from "where=some_key"

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is a difference (And this is one reason why you should never use a developement database that has significantly fewer records than the production database, you don't want to find performance problems when you push to Prod).

First assume you are going to return all the records. If you have 100 record table joined to a 100 record table the most records that coudl be returned is 10,000 recirds (this would be a cross join)
the most records you would have returned in a million record table joined to a million record table is 1,000,000,000,000. Clearly just returning that number of records across a network connnection will take longer just like printing a million pages woudl take longer than printing 100 pages.

Next the indexes  on the 100 record table will probably not be used as all of it can easily fit into memory. But the larger tables may use the indexes, so there is an extra lookup step (which speed the query immeasurably over not using an index in a large table), but more critically, they may not be used for some queries be able to use the index. Suppose you do a search with this where condition "WHERE Field1 LIKE '%test%'. Now the index cant be used and teh contents of a million records must each be checked. Does it take you longer to read a million pages than it take to read 100? So too will it take the database longer to read a million records.

Comment: thanks for your answer , I was searching for how the MYSQL join tables and it seem that invisal has good answer  , also think of this query :  SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 WHERE table1.t = table2.t LIMIT 100 ,  if I want to create a database , one think that I should keep in mind is that there should any fact of tables rows on speed. even I think it is impossible .